# Entire Page is loading

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pageload, expression-web

I have three menus. "Personal Info" "Mobile Info" "Documents" each buttons have their own link/page that displays a GridView. Now, when I click the other menu, the browser loads my entire page that causes so long to load the other page. I want to change that thing.

Now, what i want to do is. I just want only to load the area which the gridview located. Example: If i click the Personal Info button, the PersonalInfo_Gridview will appear in that area, then when I click the Mobile Info Button the PersonalInfo_Gridview will replace by MobileInfo_Gridview without loading the entire page.

here's my screenshot of my 3 menus:
[image]

How can i do that? I'm using Microsoft Expression Web, and ASP.NET please help.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow i didn't try any.

Comment: @Milind I already downlaoded the AjaxToolkit. I don't know how to configur it. because they don't have examples using Expression Web.

Comment: try this, use only one `GridView` and put it in an `UpdatePanel`. Include the `GridView` to your `asyncpostback` trigger. After that, for every click of the link, you can change the data bounded to your `GridView`.

Comment: Thanks @BlackHatShadow i'll try that i'll post here if it's working

Comment: I'm working on a project here that's why I understand clearly what are you trying to do. I suggest that you create your customize `GridView` for your system.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow I have a favor? can we chat in messenger. im going to send you my files. I think you can do it in just a minimal time? please. I don't have much time to do it please? if it's okay to you.

Comment: ow, sorry @PetersonPilares, I have to go home early. Currently I'm in the office. You can do it. Just follow the link nunespascal provide. It's all there. Goodluck.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow okay :) thanks to you also :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to update your data.

> using the UpdatePanel control, you can enable a Web page to
>   participate in partial-page updates without writing any client script.
>   If you want, you can add custom client script to enhance the client
>   user experience. When you use an UpdatePanel control, the page
>   behavior is browser independent and can potentially reduce the amount
>   of data that is transferred between client and server.

Look at how to set different triggers to use the menu buttons to trigger the udpate.

Refer: [Understanding ASP.NET UpdatePanel Triggers](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

Answer (score 1):

just like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlTabs" runat="server" >
         <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPersonalInfo" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnMobileInfo" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDocuments" />
         </Triggers>
         <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="ucLAD"/>
         <asp:Button Text="Personal Info" ID="btnPersonalInfo"  runat="server" Onclick="btnPersonalInfo_Click" />
         <asp:Button Text="Mobile Info" ID="btnMobileInfo"  runat="server" Onclick="btnMobileInfo_Click" />
         <asp:Button Text="Documents" ID="btnDocuments"  runat="server" Onclick="btnDocuments_Click" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now, to update your GridView, place your scripts on the `OnClick` action or method like this:

```
    protected void btnPersonalInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // your action here to update your GridView
    }
    protected void btnMobileInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // your action here to update your GridView
    }
    protected void btnDocuments_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // your action here to update your GridView
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) it's very useful. I can only accept 1 answer here. hmmm :) I just vote up your answer.

Comment: Hello i have a new problem. Hope u can help me. here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594513/data-are-missing-after-updating