# Data are missing after updating

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rows, insert-update

Okay I'll discuss my problem with images so we can solve it easily. Hoping.

First, The image below shows the PersonalInfo gridview under PersonalInfo.aspx
[image]

Second, The image below shows the MobileInfo gridview under MobileINfo.aspx[image]

Third, now we are going to edit the record in this page MobileInfo.aspx[image]

Fourth, Image below I thought everything works perfectly because the data has been updated. But...[image]

Fifth and last, I went back in PersonalInfo.aspx but it gives me this...Data has been deleted[image]

Here's my code for PersonalInfo.aspx

```
<asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" ID="AccessDataSource1" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [DriversRecords] WHERE [ID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [DriversRecords] ([Username], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleName], [Address], [Age], [Gender], [ContactNumber], [PlateNumber], [Color], [Brand], [LiscensedNumber], [SSSNumber], [TIN], [Type], [Model], [BirthDay], [BirthMonth], [BirthYear]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [DriversRecords] SET [Username] = ?, [Password] = ?, [FirstName] = ?, [LastName] = ?, [MiddleName] = ?, [Address] = ?, [Age] = ?, [Gender] = ?, [ContactNumber] = ?, [PlateNumber] = ?, [Color] = ?, [Brand] = ?, [LiscensedNumber] = ?, [SSSNumber] = ?, [TIN] = ?, [Type] = ?, [Model] = ?, [BirthDay] = ?, [BirthMonth] = ?, [BirthYear] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?" DataFile="_private/records.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DriversRecords]">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Age" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="SSSNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="TIN" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Model" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthDay" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthMonth" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthYear" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Age" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="SSSNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="TIN" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Model" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthDay" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthMonth" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthYear" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

and Here's my code for MobileInfo.aspx

```
<asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" ID="AccessDataSource1" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [DriversRecords] WHERE [ID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [DriversRecords] ([Username], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleName], [Address], [Age], [Gender], [ContactNumber], [PlateNumber], [Color], [Brand], [LiscensedNumber], [SSSNumber], [TIN], [Type], [Model], [BirthDay], [BirthMonth], [BirthYear]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [DriversRecords] SET [Username] = ?, [Password] = ?, [FirstName] = ?, [LastName] = ?, [MiddleName] = ?, [Address] = ?, [Age] = ?, [Gender] = ?, [ContactNumber] = ?, [PlateNumber] = ?, [Color] = ?, [Brand] = ?, [LiscensedNumber] = ?, [SSSNumber] = ?, [TIN] = ?, [Type] = ?, [Model] = ?, [BirthDay] = ?, [BirthMonth] = ?, [BirthYear] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?" DataFile="_private/records.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [DriversRecords]">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Age" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="SSSNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="TIN" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Model" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthDay" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthMonth" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthYear" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Age" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="SSSNumber" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="TIN" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="Model" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthDay" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthMonth" Type="String" />
                <asp:parameter Name="BirthYear" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

I hope someone can help me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see here is that you have the same `UpdateCommand` on the two pages, but on the second page that you make the update, the values are all null or not exist and the result is that you actually deletes them.

Go on this UpdateCommand of the page `MobileINfo.aspx` and remove the field that you do not actually use - keep only the one that you actually change them - or the rest are refereed to data that not exist and there fore they are delete.

`UpdateCommand="UPDATE [DriversRecords] SET [Username] = ?, [Password] = ?, [FirstName] = ?, [LastName] = ?, [MiddleName] = ?, [Address] = ?, [Age] = ?, [Gender] = ?, [ContactNumber] = ?, [PlateNumber] = ?, [Color] = ?, [Brand] = ?, [LiscensedNumber] = ?, [SSSNumber] = ?, [TIN] = ?, [Type] = ?, [Model] = ?, [BirthDay] = ?, [BirthMonth] = ?, [BirthYear] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?"`

Eg, on the second page the `LiscensedNumber` exit, but the `Gender` not. After your update the Gender will update to null, or empty string.